# Mixed effects model specifying a standard deviation for the random effect of just one group

Tags: mixed-model

In a mixed effects model, is it possible to manually specify a standard deviation of 0 for the random effect for one group, and estimate the standard deviation of the random effect for another group? Imagine the comparison of two machines' output. Machine 1 is user-dependent, and Machine 2 isn't. So for Machine 1, we have 20 individuals (for example) use the machine, and for Machine 2, we have just 1 individual use the machine, and we compare the outputs.

We want to incorporate a random person effect for Machine 1 but not for Machine 2. Is there a way to specify no random effect (or a random effect with very small standard deviation) just for Machine 2?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean when you say "Machine 1 is user-dependent" ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply!  I mean that Machine 1 will produce different values depending on who uses it (i.e., based on the person's skill in using Machine 1).  However, Machine 2 will always produce the same value, regardless of who uses it.  Thank you again!!

Comment: I guess that, with R, something like lmer(y ~ (0+machine1|id), data=da) would work, where machine1 is a dummy indicator, which has value 0 for machine2 and value 1 for machine 1.

Comment: Should be: lmer(y ~ machine1 + (0+machine1|id), data=da)